Error while importing libraries in Apache Airflow Dag
I am trying to use OpenAI Library in my Airflow Dag named:llm_workflow_dag.py, whenever I am trying to use any library other than this as well it gives me an error on UI:

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/llm_workflow_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 488,
in _call_with_frames_removed   File
"/opt/airflow/dags/llm_workflow_dag.py", line 10, in 
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai'

I have already installed this using requirments.txt and checked on webserver and tried pip installing it over it, it shows me requirements already satisfied
My docker-compose.yml looks like this for webserver:
      airflow-webserver:
    image: apache/airflow:2.10.2
    container_name: airflow-webserver
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - airflow-scheduler
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME=admin        
      - _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD=admin        
      # - PYTHONPATH=/opt/airflow/modules  # Add this line to set PYTHONPATH

    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./modules:/opt/airflow/modules  # Mapping the modules folder
      - ./airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg  
      - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt  
      - "C:/Users/navthars/Desktop/PENV/.venv:/usr/local/airflow/.venv"  
      # - ./modules:/opt/airflow/modules  # Correct volume mapping for modules

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: >
      bash -c "pip install -r /requirements.txt && airflow webserver"
  airflow-init:
    image: apache/airflow:2.10.2
    container_name: airflow-init
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      # - ./modules:/opt/airflow/modules  # Mapping the modules folderd
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/bash -c
      "airflow db init"
    command: "echo Initializing Airflow Database"

My Folder structure looks like this.


I had created a dockerfile like this which solved the issue :
# Dockerfile for custom Airflow image

# Use the base Airflow image
FROM apache/airflow:2.10.2

# Switch to root user to install system-level packages (if needed)
USER root

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

# Switch to airflow user before installing Python packages
USER airflow

# Install Python packages from requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

I have created multiple containers in a single image and was not installing all the libraries over all the containers which lead to this issue.
